# Get recently added / updated users from Azure Active Directory

Tags: filter, user, microsoft-graph, last-modified-date, azure-active-directory

I want to fetch all the users from Azure Active Directory who are recently modified/added using Graph API SDK.

I tried to search for the lastModified, or Modified property which returns the last modified date on which the filter can be applied but did not find any.  (Ref: [User Properties](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties))

Is there any other property available, which can be used to query the data?